# Proper maturity in the Merton's model

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, credit-risk, black-scholes-merton, structured-credit

I am working on a credit rating project using Merton's model. Basically it adopts Black-Scholes that equity value can be viewed as a call option with a strike price of face value of debts. Since the maturities of different debts vary and I have a long list of companies, choosing a proper maturity of debts for all is a difficult task. any good advice for the problem?

Comment: You mean:  equity value= a call option on the assets with a strike price equal to the debts.

Answer (score 2):

The original Merton model takes a simplified view of the debt structure in assuming the total value of outstanding debt (or some portion thereof) $D$ matures at a specified time $T$.  Shareholders are long a European call option on the firm value struck at the face value of debt and bondholders are long a risk-free zero coupon bond and short a European put option struck at the face value of debt. To implement the model the time to expiration of the options is taken as $T$.

Such assumptions about $D$ and $T$ appear to be vast oversimplifications of the capital structure of real firms. However, they can be handled in a way that may very well be useful depending upon the purpose for the model.  It may be better to apply a simple, parsimonious model consistently.  For example $T$ may be taken as the duration of the debt or even a fixed horizon with $D$ taken as some representative measure of the outstanding debt.  Credit ratings and estimates of default probability are generally applied in a relative way across debt issuers in portfolio construction.

The firm KMV (acquired by Moody's) developed one of the first commercially available credit models providing estimates of default probability for a one-year horizon.  **The KMV approach is based on the Merton model in conjunction with calibration to historical data .**  With this enhancement, it is not necessary to be overly concerned with all details of the capital structure but rather to use a consistent simple specification that is amenable to calibration.

KMV found that the model was most effective by setting $D$ to be the sum of the total face value of short-term debt (maturing within a year) and one half of the total face value of long-term debt (maturing beyond a year).

The rationale for KMV's approach -- which makes a lot of sense -- is that default is driven more by the inability to service short-term debt because the  issuer can often negotiate restructuring of long-term debt with greater flexibility.